# Uppercase field is not bound properly in template

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

This is more for reference for others as a real question, since I guess I have already understood what is going on. But it took a while, so I will document it here.

In one of my models, I have a field named `VAT`. I try to bind to this field in an template:

```
{{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="VAT" id="VAT-id" placeholder="VAT" required="true"}}
```

But this is not working, which was kind of surprising, and took some time to understand.

Some questions:

- Is this a limitation of `Ember` or `ember-data`? (I guess `ember-data`?)
- How is an uppercase field name translated by ember? There is a section in the documentation describing how the [REST adapter](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_underscored-attribute-names) transforms underscored attributes, but nothing regarding uppercase fields.
- What can I do to refer to this field using the real name? (I guess it is not possible?)

The only workaround I know is to do:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Company', {
    ...
    vat        : {key: 'VAT'},
});
```

which still does not allow to use the real name in the templates; I must still use `vat` (in lowercase). I guess it is really not possible to use the original uppercase field name using `ember-data`?

### NOTE

Oh, and don't forget that the `REST` adapter must be created **after** it has been fully configured, otherwise the configuration is not used. This has been a source of much confusion too. So do it like this:

```
App.Adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({ ... });
App.Adapter.configure('plurals', { ... });
App.Adapter.map('App.Company', { ... });
... more adapter configuration
```

And *now* you can do:

```
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 13,
    adapter: App.Adapter.create(),
    ...
});
```

If you invert the order, Ember will not say anything, but the configuration will not be active.

Answer (score 0):

> which still does not allow to use the real name in the templates; I must still use vat (in lowercase). I guess it is really not possible to use the original uppercase field name using ember-data?

You guessed right, it is by design that Uppercase key names are not supported, so your workaround is pretty much the way to go, because there is no easy way to configure this in another way.

Hope it helps.